# How to extract a timezone's current time with system.currentTimeMillis()?

Tags: java

public class ShowCurrentTime

{

public static void main(String[] args)

```
{

 // Obtain the total milliseconds

 long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();

 // Obtain the total seconds

 long totalSeconds = totalMilliseconds / 1000;

 // Compute the current second in the minute in the hour

 long currentSecond = totalSeconds % 60;

 // Obtain the total minutes

 long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;

 // Compute the current minute in the hour

 long currentMinute = (totalMinutes % 60);

 // Obtain the total hours

 long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;

 // Compute the current hour

 long currentHour = totalHours % 24;

 // Display results

 System.out.println("Current time is " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond + "GMT");

}
```

}

---

Running these codes, gives the GMT, how to configure it to get the current time of a certain timezone like GMT +5:30 (IST)?

Answer (score 0):

times in Java are UTC, if you need to display it in a different timezone you can use the Calendar class and set your desired timezone